# How to concat a String with a table field with sequel

Tags: ruby, concatenation, sequel

I want to replace a legacy sql-statement with a Sequel-version and have problems to solve create a concated field.

An example:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:test){
  field :text, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 5
}
DB[:test].insert('aa')
DB[:test].insert('bb')
DB[:test].insert('cc')


sel = DB[:test].select(
  (:text + '1' ).as(:concat)
  )
puts sel.sql
puts sel.all
```

This works fine, the result is:

```
SELECT (`text` || '1') AS 'concat' FROM `test`
{:concat=>"aa1"}
{:concat=>"bb1"}
{:concat=>"cc1"}
```

My problem: I need '1aa'. With SQL this is no problem:

```
puts DB.fetch("SELECT ('1' || `text`) AS 'concat' FROM `test`").all
```

But with ruby I get a syntax error ( `can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)`:

```
sel = DB[:test].select(
  ('1' + :text).as(:concat)
  )
```

It's interesting, this works again:

```
sel = DB[:test].select(
  (:text + '1' + :text).as(:concat)
  )
puts sel.sql
puts sel.all
```

But how can I concat a String?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just look at [Sequels documentation](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html) to String Operators

```
sel = DB[:test].select(
  Sequel.join(['1', :text]).as(:concat)
  )
puts sel.sql
puts sel.all
```

(Remark: [answering your own question is a good thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to) - and I needed some time to get it).